# Function not setting text of paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, function, innerhtml

I'm trying to set the value of a paragraph tag with the class `rules`. It should switch between a, b, c, etc. every 4 seconds and repeat. For some reason, the function isn't running at all and there are no errors in the developer tools of chrome. Nothing changes when I call the function with `<body onload="rulesSlideshow">` instead.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.onload = function rulesSlideshow() {
        setTimeout(setRule("a"), 4000);
        setTimeout(setRule("b"), 4000);
        setTimeout(setRule("c"), 4000);
        setTimeout(setRule("d"), 4000);
        setTimeout(setRule("e"), 4000);
        rulesSlideshow();
    }

    function setRule(rule) {
        document.querySelector("rules").innerHTML = rule;
    }
</script>


<p id="rule" class="rules"></p>
```

**EDIT:** By removing the `document.onload =` and adding `<body onload="rulesSlideshow()">` I can get the code to run (courtesy of [Daniel Beck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3412322/daniel-beck)). Despite this, my code can't find the paragraph tag.

Comment: All timeouts are set to 4 seconds so they run at the same time...

Comment: The above plus your function isn't callable. You're not declaring a function in global scope, your placing a function inside the scope of document.onload.

Comment: But the code isn't running _at all_. If I put a `window.alert("Test");` at the top it never triggers.

Comment: @zfrisch Wouldn't that be avoided with my `<body onload="x">` attempt though?

Comment: I believe you want `onload="rulesSlideshow()"`.  But you're also trying to define the script with its own `document.onload` handler; choose one or the other.

Comment: @DanielBeck Oops, my mistake. Even still, now I'm getting the error that I can't set the property 'innerHtml' of null. The script can't find my paragraph tag even though it is in my HTML.

Comment: There are several other issues with your code, yes. I'm midway through writing up an answer.

Comment: Your query selector is not valid. If you are trying to select by class it should be `document.querySelector(".rules")`, or by id it should be `document.querySelector("#rules")`. And as others say, your timeouts all fire at the same time.

Comment: @DanielBeck While not advisable, the name `rulesSlidshow` isn't hurting anything. The function will still be called in `onload`. The problem is that all the timers fire immediately, one after the other and that the selector is `rules` when it should be `.rules`

Comment: @ScottMarcus I thought that would only happen in an async function.

Comment: @ScottMarcus you may have misunderstood what I was saying.  The question contains `onload="foo"` -- it should be `onload="foo()"` for the function to be called instead of just referenced.

Comment: @DanielBeck I've just fixed that (on my side) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Defining the onload handler

If you're trying to call the function from via an onload attribute in the DOM, you need to call the function, not just reference it; so that should be `<body onload="rulesSlideshow()">`.

If you prefer to define the onload handler in code, either use an anonymous function:

```
document.onload = function() {...};
```

...or a named function applied to document.onload as a reference:

```
var rulesSlideshow = function() {...}
document.onload = rulesSlideshow; // no parens this time, since you're assigning the function to the handler here, not calling it.
```

Either call the handler from a DOM attribute, or define it in code -- don't do both.  (It's a good idea to keep your javascript as separate from the DOM as much as possible, so many people will recommend against using inline event attributes like `<body onload="...">` and instead define those handlers in code -- but either technique will still work perfectly well.)

#### querySelector

Since you're looking for a classname, you need to include the ".":

```
document.querySelector(".rules").innerHTML = rule;
```

#### Timeouts

Since all your timeouts have the same time value, they'll all run simultaneously (or close enough) -- so you will only see the results of the last one.   If you're looking to have a four second interval between each call, they need different timeout values.

Also, since rulesSlideshow calls itself immediately after running, you'll wind up with a stack overflow.  That, too, needs a setTimeout (though since what you're doing is having the function recur periodically, calling it once with `setInterval` may be more appropriate.)

#### functions within setTimeout

setTimeout expects to receive a function, but you're passing it the results from calling a function. If you didn't need a parameter on `setRule` you could just use this shorthand:

```
setTimeout(setRule, 4000)
```

But with the param, you'll need an anonymous wrapper:

```
setTimeout(function() {setRule("x")}, 4000)
```

#### Demo

Putting that all together (I've switched it from an onload to an onclick, because onload is difficult to demonstrate within a stack snippet, but the rest is the same):

```js
var rulesSlideshow = function() {
  console.log("Called rulesSlideshow");
  setTimeout(function() {setRule("a")}, 4000);
  setTimeout(function() {setRule("b")}, 8000);
  setTimeout(function() {setRule("c")}, 12000);
  setTimeout(function() {setRule("d")}, 16000);
  setTimeout(function() {setRule("e")}, 20000);
  setTimeout(rulesSlideshow, 20000); // used same timeout as above, because there's a 4s delay before this function does anything.
}

document.onclick = rulesSlideshow;

function setRule(rule) {
  console.log("setRule");
  document.querySelector(".rules").innerHTML = rule;
}
```

```html
(Click anywhere to start)
<p id="rule" class="rules"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I love the way you've layed out your answer (especially helpful to a noob at JS like me!).

Comment: @DavidWheatley This really isn't the best solution. It uses several techniques that are wasteful and/or outdated.

Comment: @ScottMarcus in-line event attributes are currently out of fashion, to be sure; and personally I’d have used setInterval instead of a series of settimeouts... but “wasteful”? In general I try to answer questions without completely rewriting the asker’s code unless they’re doing something actively dangerous or clearly incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues, but the biggest were that

- your calls to `setTimeout` were invoking the functions immediately
  because you were using parenthesis to pass the argument, but that
  invokes the function. `setTimeout` requires a function reference
- your `.querySelector` was not going to find the element with the
  class because you didn't have a `.` in front of the class name

See the comments inline below for a cleaner solution (I'm using one second here to make it quicker to see the results):

```js
var el = null;  // prepare to hold a reference to the output element
var vals = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];  // values to enumerate
var idx = 0;  // counter to keep track of how many times to call a timer
var timer = null;  // will hold reference to timer

// When the document is fully parsed
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  el = document.getElementById("rule"); // set up reference to output element
  timer = setTimeout(setRule, 1000);  // set up the timer, don't invoke the function with ()
});

// Function to be called by timer
function setRule() {
  // Check the counter to see if we still have values to enumerate
  if(idx < vals.length){
    // We do, so set the output element to the correct array value
    el.textContent = vals[idx++];
    // Call the timer again
    setTimeout(setRule, 1000);
  }
  
}
```

```html
<p id="rule"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have three problems:

- You are **assigning** your `rulesSlideshow()` function to `onload`, but never actually **invoking** it. You can achieve this by adding brackets to the end of the function as `function() { ... }()`, creating an **[Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)**.
- Your selector `querySelector("rules")` won't actually target anything; you need to specify the class with the `.` prefix as `.querySelector(".rules")`.
- You're setting all your timeouts to `4000`. Because these will run **asynchronously**, they will all trigger at the **same time**. Thus, you'll only see the final output (`e`). To truly 'offset' the output, you either need to set the timeouts **within** one another, or make use of [**chained promises**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) so that they run sequentially.

This can all be seen in the following:

```js
document.onload = function rulesSlideshow() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    setRule("a");
    setTimeout(function() {
      setRule("b");
      setTimeout(function() {
        setRule("c");
        setTimeout(function() {
          setRule("d");
          setTimeout(function() {
            setRule("e");
          }, 4000);
        }, 4000);
      }, 4000);
    }, 4000);
  }, 4000);
}();

function setRule(rule) {
  document.querySelector(".rules").innerHTML = rule;
}
```

```html
<p id="rule" class="rules"></p>
```

Also, note that you don't need to actually invoke `rulesShowshow()` within `rulesSlideshow()` itself; this has been removed from the above snippet.

Comment: Actually, while the `setTimeout()` calls are asynchronous, your explanation for what's happening with them is not correct. They won't run at the same time. They will get stacked up in the event loop and run, one after the other, but without any delay between them.  But, in actuality, the OP's `setTimeout()` calls won't result in anything at all happening because he incorrectly placed a function invocation as the first argument to the method: `setTimeout(setRule("a"), 4000)`. With this code, `setRule("a")` will run immediately and the return value is what will be invoked after the delay....

Comment: ... Since `setRule("a")` doesn't return a value, each of the method calls are essentially this: `setTimeout(undefined, 4000)`.